# how to get access to newly added functions inside a javascript class

Tags: javascript

If in a Javascript class there are few properties which are added initially and were available   through prototype.Now if some new properties or functions are added to the class ,how can they be accessed to all existing and newly created functions. Note that the class is not readily available to everyone.

```
function Foo(){
    this.name="";
    this.place="";
}
```

In `House.js` i had used  `Foo.prototype=House();`

In `college.js` i had used  `Foo.prototype = College();`

now this Foo() is modified to

```
function Foo(){
    this.name="";
    this.place="";
    var books=function Books(){...some implementaion};
}
```

What will happen if `House.books` before and after modification of the class.

Comment: did you mean to say this.books = ... inside Foo() { } ? At the moment you just placed it in a local variable.

Comment: The code is a bit confusing IMO. E.g. `Foo.prototype = College();` simply override the changes in the preceding line, so what's the point? Also, you cannot "modify" a function, you can overwrite with another function, but it would not be related to the previous function at all.

Comment: sorry edited properly

Comment: `House.books` will never exist in any situation with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all:

```
Foo.prototype = House();
Foo.prototype = College();
```

That won't work. The college prototype will replace the house prototype, so the first assignment has no effect.

Creating a local variable inside the constructor function will only make that available inside that function. I think that you mean:

```
function Foo(){

  this.name="";
  this.place="";

  this.books=function Books(){...some implementaion};
}
```

That will add the `books` property to all instances of the object, so it will be available whatever you put in the prototype, even if you have some property in the prototype with the same name.

Comment: House and College are not used simulatanously .My idea is its only an assigment to 2 different file namely house.js and college,js...Will this case has any effects

Comment: @GustyWind: If you only use one or the other for any specific object, then that's not a problem.